# Spring Boot default exceptions automatically mapped to a http status code

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, exception, http-status-codes

**In my spring boot rest api app,I want to define a automatic method for unhandled exception.Suppose client give wrong password in login endpoint.The response is 403 forbidden without any message.but i want to give some message as a response and want to give all the unhandled exception to this same format of message.
I try this:**

```
    @ResponseStatus
    @ControllerAdvice
    public class RestErrorResponse extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
   
        @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
        public ResponseEntity<ErrorMessage> handleServerError(Exception exception){
            ErrorMessage message = new ErrorMessage(
                    "Failed",
                    exception.getMessage(),
                    400
            );
            return ResponseEntity.status(400).body(message);
        }
    }
```

**The ErrorMessage class**

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ErrorMessage {
    private String status;
    private String message;
    private Integer statusCode;
}
```

**This is work.But the problem is i need to define the code itself.Here the code is 400.But i don't know which exception is happened.I need the status code daynamically anyhow.
Find a answer in stackoverflow and i also try this below code**

```
 @ResponseStatus
        @ControllerAdvice
        public class RestErrorResponse extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
       
            @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
            public ResponseEntity<ErrorMessage> handleServerError(Exception exception,HttpServletResponse response){
                ErrorMessage message = new ErrorMessage(
                        "Failed",
                        exception.getMessage(),
                        response.getStatus()
                );
                return ResponseEntity.status(response.getStatus()).body(message);
            }
        }
```

But the `response.getStatus()` always return 200.

Comment: You can handle specific exceptions in separate methods using `@ExceptionHandler(MyException.class)` annotation.

Comment: You don't get my point?I want daynamic exception handler for all unhandeled exception so that i can send back a same formatted message to client